# Can Laravel ignore further validation rules if you use exclude_if and it is TRUE?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using the latest version of Laravel.

I am using Validator in my store controller and essentially I have a field called "current" which is required and is expected to be boolean. I also have a 2nd field, which is optional, called "to_date" of which the javascript plugin (moment.js) will provide either a date, or if null, provides a string "Invalid date" to the controller.

I wish to be able to validate "to_date" as a date using Validator if "current" is equal to 0. If "current" is equal to 1 then I wish to ignore validation for field "to_date"

My code started as:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'current' => 'required|boolean',
        'to_date' => 'date',
]);
```

But of course this failed because when "to_date" is not provided, the front-end provides a string "Invalid date" which fails the validation. And then I explored Laravel's validation rules a bit more and found 'exclude_if' which seemed to be appropriate.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'current' => 'required|boolean',
        'to_date' => 'exclude_if:current,1|date',
]);
```

This still didn't work because whilst it appears to "exclude it" from the $validator array, it still goes to the 'date' validation and fails. And so then I looked at 'bail' which is supposed to discontinue validation when Validator hits its first fail, however this doesn't work either because exclude_if doesn't fail when it runs, and the script still hits 'date' and fails.

Any help/pointers appreciated.

I am sure I can resolve this by wrapping Validator in an if statement and doing some logic to check whether to include "to_date" in Validator but this seems a bit smelly and not very tidy.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2):

Tested with Laravel 6.18.7 and your code works correctly for me.  If you're still having issues, you might want to check your input.

Example code I used in tinker:

```
>>> Validator::make([
    'current' => 1,
    'to_date' => 'invalid-data',
], [
    'current' => 'required|boolean',
    'to_date' => 'exclude_if:current,1|date',
])->passes();
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are intentionally providing bad data "invalid date".

This will trigger the validation failure because data is present.

`exclude_if` simply excludes the data from the array after validation.

The best solution is to not send bad data, and do `required_if:current,0|date` and when `to_date` is empty and required, it will fail the date validation portion.